# Share This - WordPress plugin is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, sharethis

I had installed "[Share This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/share-this/)" Plugin in my Wordpress Site. It was working before. But, now it stops suddenly, I tried to deactivate and re-install the plugin. But, still the problem exists. Everything is OK in plugin Configurations. There is some code issue. I tried to find out but couldn't.
Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the plugin itself. I also tried it previously. This is an issue that you should rise with the plugin author.

Comment: Thank you @PieterGoosen
BTW, I just realized that the plugin is not loading while visiting the website. But, admin can see that the plugin is installed and he can configure the plugin changes..

Comment: True. Somewhere the execution on the front end is missing. If you are running a test install, download "Hook Sniffer" plugin, activate it and load any front end page. The plugin will print all the hooks run on that specific page. From this you will be able so see if plugin is executed or not. Just don't run this plugin on a live site

Comment: I don't have a test site. can I install it on live site and remove after checking?

Comment: You can do that, just remember to remove it immediatly. Like I said, it prints a list of hooks when a page is loaded, so it will look funny for someone visiting your site if that plugin is activated

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, I did install the "Hook Sniffer", but, the website  stop working. Moreover, I just noticed that the plugin is working on other wordpress websites..